# How can I wait for loading all the elements from JSON in fabric.js?

Tags: json, canvas, fabricjs

there is a method
..... loadFromJSON (json, callback)

he takes the JSON string and adds it to the canvas

The fact is that in this line there are links to pictures that need to be added ..

after calling this method, I call the method of enumerating the added elements to canvas
.getObjects () ....

The fact is that getObjects () does not return anything

I figured out and understood that loadFromJSON worked for a long time, that I execute it, and then immediately getObjects, but loadFromJSON has not managed to add everything to the canvas and there's nothing there because of this .... and I can not work with objects any more, although in the browser I see them, they are added ..

How to be? How can I wait for the complete loadFromJSON to work, then to add all the added from the canvas?

in the code:

loadFromJSON ()
then getObjects ()

but in the console everything is different, first comes the receipt, and then all the pictures are added to the canvas

Comment: did you you call the render method?

Comment: as you mentioned `json, callback` are two arguments for `loadFromJSON()`, that callback function called after loading everything from json. so use `getObjects()` inside callback function.